# How to get size of ctypes array on memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I created an array using `ctypes` library in python. I wanted to know the size of array in bytes. I tried `sys.getsizeof()`. No matter how large of an array I create this function is always returning 120.

```
E = (10 * ctypes.py_object)()
for j in range(10):
    E[j] = 0
print(sys.getsizeof(E))
output: 120
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `ctypes.sizeof` instead:

```
import ctypes

E = (10 * ctypes.py_object)()
for j in range(10):
    E[j] = 0

print(ctypes.sizeof(E))
```

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof